# Integrating PV (protein viewer) with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to display a protein in a Vue component using PV. However, I have no luck in actually displaying the protein. The canvas stays blank, however, with correct colour of the background, as set in PV options.

In the console, following information is displayed - I believe PV believes its drawing, I'm just not sure where :

```
bio-pv.js?2f7e:8479 Mol.deriveConnectivity: 27.666015625ms
bio-pv.js?2f7e:9415 imported 1 chain(s), 295 residue(s)
bio-pv.js?2f7e:9465 pdb: 80.593994140625ms
bio-pv.js?2f7e:5342 cartoon: 55.198974609375ms
```

The following is a snippet of the single page component attempting to use PV.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="pvpanel" ref="pvpanel"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import pv from "bio-pv";

export default {
  name: "ProteinViewPanel",
  mounted: function() {
  let viewPanel = this;
  this.$nextTick().then(function() {
      let viewer = pv.Viewer(viewPanel.$refs.pvpanel, {
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        antialias: true,
        quality: "medium",
        background: "black"
      });

      viewer.on("viewerReady", function() {
        pv.io.fetchPdb(`./api/downloadpdbs/1cqw`, protein => {
          viewer.cartoon("mol", protein);
        });
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Probably because `this.$refs.pvpanel` is not yet available in the DOM in the `mounted` lifecycle hook. You might want to wait for `this.$nextTick()` before instantiating `pv.Viewer()`

Comment: add a small delay between component mounted and instantiating pv to the DOM element. setTimeout or nextTick can be used

Comment: I have moved the code to run after $nextTick() promise, however, no change occurred. I also think this is not an issue, because the PV seems initialized properly with a background colour depending on options.

Comment: Can you update your code that shows how you integrate `this.$nextTick()` into your code? Also, it might make sense at this point to [create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated the code with $nextTick. I will try to produce the example.

Comment: @Terry Well, the protein was zoomed out way too far and in a weird place. This was fun 2 hours of my life. Figured this out while trying to create a minimal example, so thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protein was zoomed out way too far.